# What is the best unit testing framework to test node.js app using express and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jasmine

I tried couple of frameworks and libraries like jasmine-node, supertest, mockgoose, http-mocks... What is the best combination for unit testing a node app using express and mongoose?

The problem is the asynchronous nature and use of callbacks instead of promises(especially in mongoose).... Can anyone post a running example where you mock the mongoose calls?

Comment: Can you add a little more information about what you're struggling with? I have successfully used mockgoose in my tests, so I would definitely recommend that. Have you discovered the done argument for tests with async code? See here: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi, thanx for the response. For my unit test, I was finally able to use Mocha as testRunner, Sinon.js for mocking and chai for assertions. I was able to mock the moongoose calls.